# Applying a css file on a div inside a document using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded an html5 template that uses bootstrap. So when I try to write html code, I have unusual results (I think it's caused by bootstrap) so I want to know how to use my own css file on a div element inside the page ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include a verifiable example of your issue (html/css).

Comment: Could you create an example on jsfiddle.net? It also help to go to the template, right-click to View Source and compare/contrast its mark-up with what you're creating. Later files overwrite earlier one in html pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer your css as you normally would.  Create a css file and then refer it in the head of the html document.  For example:

```
<link href="css/mywebsite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If I was doing it, I would also have my bootstrap css file linked as well and placed in the same folder.
Your question isn't very clear, let me know if this is what you mean.

Hope this Helps

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you reference your CSS file after you reference the bootstrap file. Example,

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/mywebsite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then if you want to override any bootstrap element you redefine the same class or the id in your CSS file and add your attributes, along with your custom elements. Hope this helps.

Comment: Dude...don't copy other people's answers. Add comments if you want to add to it.

Comment: I did not copy Conor Graham's answer. I would suggest reading my answer first. Although i used Conor Graham's answer as an example if you carefully read my answer you will see that my answer is different from Conor Graham's answer. Learn how to read or take time to understand what you read.